# Lista enlazada en C

Tags: c, algoritmos, punteros

Primero creo la lista, luego verifico si está vacía o no, después paso los valores que quiero que tengan la lista, pero cuando imprimo las listas no me salen los valores que yo le pasé. ¿Cómo hago para que imprima lo que le estoy pasando?

```
struct alumnos
{
    char nombre[30];
    int cedula;
    int telefono;
    struct alumnos *siguiente;
};

typedef struct alumnos _nodo;

_nodo *crearLista(_nodo *apuntador);

bool listaVacia(_nodo *apuntador);

_nodo *insetarEnLista(char nombre[], int cedula, int telefono, _nodo *apuntador);

void imprimirLista (_nodo *apuntador);

_nodo *crearLista(_nodo *apuntador)
{
    return (apuntador = NULL);
}

bool listaVacia(_nodo *apuntador)
{
    if (apuntador == NULL)
    {
        return (true);
    }
    else
    {
        return (false);
    }
}

_nodo *insetarEnLista(char nombre[], int cedula, int telefono, _nodo *apuntador)
{

    _nodo *registroNuevo, *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    registroNuevo = (_nodo *) malloc(sizeof(_nodo));

    if (registroNuevo != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(registroNuevo->nombre, nombre);
        registroNuevo->cedula, cedula;
        registroNuevo->telefono, telefono;
        registroNuevo->siguiente = NULL;

        if (listaVacia(apuntador))
        {
            apuntador = registroNuevo;
        }
        else
        {
            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

            while (apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente != NULL)
            {
                apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
            }

            apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = registroNuevo;
        }
    }

    return apuntador;
}

void imprimirLista (_nodo *apuntador)
{
    _nodo *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntador == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA \n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(apuntador != NULL)
        {
            printf(" ------------NODO-------------- \n");
            printf("NOMBRE: %S \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);
            printf("CEDULA: %d \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->cedula);
            printf("TELEFONO: %d \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->telefono);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    /*printf("INTRODUZCA LOS NUMEROS DE CEDULA QUE DESEA IMPRIMIR \n");*/

    _nodo *iniciolista;
    int cedula, telefono;

    scanf("%d", &cedula);
    scanf("%d", &telefono);

    iniciolista = crearLista(iniciolista);

    iniciolista = insetarEnLista("Luis", cedula, telefono, iniciolista);
    iniciolista = insetarEnLista("Luis", 456, 547991, iniciolista);

    imprimirLista(iniciolista);

    return 0;
}
```

Esto es lo que me imprime:

```
-----NODO-----
NOMBRE:
CEDULA: 0
TELEFONO: 0
```

Comment: Necesitas incluir el código relevante, no hay otra manera de saber por que está mal

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta y puse el código que estoy usando

Answer (score 1):

```
_nodo *crearLista(_nodo *apuntador)
{
    return (apuntador = NULL);
}
```

Ya empezamos mal si la función que supuestamente va a crear la lista no hace **absolutamente nada**.

Se supone que esa función debería crear la lista en el caso de que la misma no existiese, luego su implementación debería parecerse más al siguiente ejemplo:

```
_nodo *crearLista(_nodo *apuntador)
{
  if( apuntador == NULL )
  {
    apuntador = (_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(_nodo));
    apuntador._siguiente = NULL;
  }

  return apuntador;
}
```

Pero claro, el problema al que te enfrentas entonces es que no puedes usar este primer elemento como un nodo válido de la lista, ya que sus campos no tienen ningún valor. Por otro lado esta función no va a ser de utilidad si el puntero de la lista no está correctamente incializado:

```
int main()
{
  _nodo *iniciolista; // ¿Qué valor tiene aquí iniciolista? Seguro que no es NULL
  iniciolista = crearLista(iniciolista); //Esta llamada no va a funcionar
```

Una posible solución sería:

```
int main()
{
  _nodo *iniciolista = crearLista(NULL);
```

Si tu idea es que el puntero a `iniciolista` apunte a un nodo válido entonces la función `crearLista` no debería existir, ya tienes ìnsetarEnLista` que hace la misma operativa y además añade un nodo válido:

```
int main()
{
  scanf("%d", &cedula);
  scanf("%d", &telefono);

  _nodo *iniciolista = insetarEnLista("Luis", cedula, telefono, NULL); // NULL para que cree la lista correctamente
}
```

El programa tiene otros vicios, como el uso de variables globales que es algo que sobra, o la total inexistencia de una función para borrar toda la lista y liberar la memoria reservada, pero tu mayor problema está aquí comentado.